# "of different" or just "different"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is it "Even if our trips are of different lengths" or "Even if our trips are different lengths"? Why?

More specifically, the construct would be [verb] [subject] [preposision?] [adjective] [object]. Is there a definitive answer for this specific construct?

Comment: *This comment might be [of] little use.* (But on the other hand, it *might* be useful!)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst138159_Linking-verb-followed-with-a-prepositional-phrase.aspx&ved=2ahUKEwjT1pGY1-niAhWCNY8KHbesAW8QFjAKegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw07ksBWn3-fVyAth0L8np1t&cshid=1560539966344

"Be" verb normally take a noun, a pronoun or an adjective; it is in a sense renaming the subject. When it is not renaming we use "prepositional phrase";  it may be adjectival or adverbial. If adjectival it is used after the noun or in the predicate portion of a sentence of subject noun or pronoun, If adverbial any where in a sentence. In the given example it is in no way renaming the subject.
A prepositional phrase may be used as an adverb telling how, when, where, how much, and why and modifying the verb and sometimes an adjective.  Adverb prepositional phrases can come anywhere in the sentence and can be moved within the sentence without changing the meaning.

- Even if our trips are '' of different lengths ''

Here the prepositional phrase is an adverbial and not being a subjective complement can never be able to forego "Of".